# A doubt in Lang's complex analysis.

Tags: complex-analysis

Lang's Complex Analysis says the following:

> Let $f$ be a function on a path $\gamma(t)$. If $f'=0$, then $f$ is constant along the whole path.

The proof mentioned says $(f(\gamma(t)))'=f'(\gamma(t)).\gamma'(t)=0$. Hence, $f(\gamma(t))$ is always constant.

I don't see how this makes sense. Can $\gamma'(t)$ never be $0$?

Thanks.

Comment: $\gamma'(t)$ can be $\neq 0$, but by hypothesis $f'(\gamma(t))=0$, and the product of $0$ with any other number is $0$.

Answer (score 4):

The proof shows $f$ is constant by showing that $f\circ \gamma$ has zero derivative. To do so, it shows that one of the factors, $f'(\gamma(t))$ is zero. It doesn't matter if the other factor is zero or not.